# Facing issues while updating BotiumBox 2.5.0 community edition

Tags: docker, docker-compose, botium-box

Using below pre-requisites:

- Docker version 18.09.7,
- docker-compose version 1.8.0

Start Botium Box by running docker-compose:

```
>docker-compose up -d

botiumboxce_redis_1 is up-to-date
botiumboxce_mysql_1 is up-to-date
botiumboxce_prisma_1 is up-to-date
botiumboxce_web_1 is up-to-date
```

but unable to hit botiumbox

When tried the below command

```
>docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
4471b9e351c7        botium/botium-box-ce:2.5.0       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 days ago          Up Less than a second       0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp   botiumboxce_web_1
aac0e5d27639        prismagraphql/prisma:1.34.10     "/bin/sh -c /app/sta…"   5 days ago          Up 18 hours                 0.0.0.0:4466->4466/tcp   botiumboxce_prisma_1
980823f62cde        mysql:5.7                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 days ago          Up 18 hours                 3306/tcp, 33060/tcp      botiumboxce_mysql_1
6e212a21b75f        redis:alpine                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago         Up 18 hours                 0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   botiumboxce_redis_1
```

again i'm getting as below:

```
4471b9e351c7        botium/botium-box-ce:2.5.0       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 days ago          Restarting (127) 6 seconds ago                            botiumboxce_web_1
aac0e5d27639        prismagraphql/prisma:1.34.10     "/bin/sh -c /app/sta…"   5 days ago          Up 18 hours                      0.0.0.0:4466->4466/tcp   botiumboxce_prisma_1
980823f62cde        mysql:5.7                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 days ago          Up 18 hours                      3306/tcp, 33060/tcp      botiumboxce_mysql_1
6e212a21b75f        redis:alpine                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago         Up 18 hours                      0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   botiumboxce_redis_1
```

I also tried removing web_1 and update it and run again, but still i get the same. Always web_1 is restarting every minute.

```
> docker-compose stop
> docker-compose rm web
> docker-compose pull
> docker-compose up -d
```

For updating botium box i used above commands.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: run "docker logs botiumboxce_web_1" to see the log output from the botium box container

Comment: when I run the above command its showing "env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory".

Comment: what operating system are you on ?

Comment: Working on linux operating system.

Comment: pls try a "docker-compose pull" once more

Comment: tried the above command getting error as below:
Pulling redis (redis:alpine)...
ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: EOF

Comment: The problem with the botium box image itself ("env: bash\r No such file or directory") is solved, I updated the image in dockerhub. The pull problem with redis is something I cannot help with, maybe something with firewall, proxy, certificate ...